# How to overwrite styles which having :root

Tags: css

I want to overwrite styles which defined with `:root` pseudo-class.

I have css like below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div><p>hello world</p></div>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        :root p{
          color: red !important;
        }
        html > div > p{
          color: green !important;
        }
    </style>    
</body>
</html>
```

I want to display color green instead of red. How can i overwrite the styles

Comment: Same as with any other, there is nothing special about the `:root` pseudo class in this regard. But your second selector doesn’t match anything, because the `html` element doesn’t have any `div` _children_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`html > div > p` does not select your element because there is a `body` element between the `html` and the `div`.

`html > body > div > p` does select your element, but the specificity is lower than `:root p`, which has a pseudo-class.

The trick is easy: two pseudo-classes are more specific than one. Use `:root:root p`

```css
:root p {
  color: red;
}
:root:root p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div><p>hello world</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use **div > p** instead of **html > div > p**

```
        div > p {
          color: green!important;
        }
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/325zcupu/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to this:

```css
:root p{
          color: red !important;
        }

:root div > p{
      color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<div><p>hello world</p></div>
```